# Can I "un-transfer" 2 existing channels with Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, transfer, unlink, disconnect

I have 2 phones connected after transfer action and now I want to "un-trasfer" them both and put them on hold listening to background music. I've tried to park, call a phantom number, etc. But every time the second phone (the one that does not perform the action) hangs up.

Can I do this without a conference call? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I did it! @arheops gave me the key with his note. I must do:
With A and B speaking
Redirect both channels to waiting:

```
Action: Redirect    
ActionID: 1234  
Channel: Channel1  
ExtraChannel: Channel2  
Exten: 000000001  
ExtraExten: 000000001  
Context: default  
ExtraContext: default  
Priority: 1  
ExtraPriority: 1
```

In extensions.conf I wrote a "waiting" called "on_hold" extension:

```
[on_hold]  
exten =>s,1,Answer()  
exten =>s,2,BackGround(onholdmusic)  
exten =>s,3,goto(on_hold,s,2)  
exten =>h,1,HangUp()
```

Now A and B are listening to music(onholdmusic), then you can call C and bridge B with C. A keeps waiting listening to music until another bridge/hang up/other action is done.

Thanks!

Comment: I realy not see difference with last link i sent you. But sure your code canbe apear more simple for yourself.

Comment: @arheops The extensions.conf code is the great difference because tells me where I need transfer both calls. There is no code for that in your last link. But thanks anyway. Again...

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can use using ami action "Transfer", not it will transfer second one to n+1 prio,so you have create special context.

Read this first
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API

After that consult this:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example:+Transfer

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Redirect

Note, to do 2 channels same time in 1.6+ you have use ExtraChannel variable.

Comment: could you please be more verbose?

Comment: Thanks @arheops for your help, I tried this: I tried to send both channels to a new simple dial plan:  
`[onhold]`  
`exten =>s,1,BackGround(music)`  
`exten =>s,2,goto(onhold,s,1)`  
`exten =>h,1,HangUp()`  
    
But both channels hanged up.